# Django debug toolbar logging

Tags: django, logging, django-debug-toolbar

In Django 1.3 I'm using `logging` for handling logs and save them to .log files or print them in console, and everything works as expected.

I also have `django-debug-toolbar` installed, but no messages are shown in the logging pane.

Somebody knows which logging handler serves the django-debug-toolbar logging pane?

**Edit**

Here is an excerpt of my `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            ...
        },
        ...
     },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        ...
        'debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/debug.log',
            'formatter': 'standard',    
        },
        ...
    },
    'loggers': {
        ...
        ...
        'myapp.debug': {     # <- THIS i the logger I would like to see in DDT 
            'handlers': ['debug','console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            ...
         },
    },
}
```

Comment: nope... the answer to that question simply explains how to use logging... I'm using some user defined loggers (via the LOGGING variable in settings.py), and I'm trying to send logs also to the django-debug-toolbar. I was sure that d-d-t used `StreamHandler` handler class in logging, but looks like it doesn't :(

Comment: The point is that there's nothing to configure. DDT automatically hooks into the Django/Python logging infrastructure. If your logs aren't showing up, it's either outside of DDT's ability to show them or (using some other way of creating logs that DDT doesn't support) there's something else wrong unrelated to DDT.

Comment: Log messages are showing up in .log files and in console, exactly in the way I've "asked" in `LOGGING`... That's the reason because I feel that maybe something is missing somewhere....

Comment: (I'll edit the question adding some code, so it will be easier for me to find where I'm wrong)

Comment: What version of DDT are you running? Probably a long shot, but there was an open issue with Django 1.3 and logging some 9 months ago.

Comment: 0.8.5... wow... how fast are released new versions of DDT! Now I'm trying to install latest version and give it a try, but seems that pip doesn't want to collaborate and keeps installing 0.8.5 instead of upgrading it to 0.9.4 :D

Comment: Try `pip install django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4`. Though, it's probably defaulting to 0.8.5 because that's the latest version on PyPi. So you can also try `pip install git+https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar.git#egg=django-debug-toolbar` (requires git being install on your machine)

Comment: Worked... I've been trying wit `pip install --upgrade django-debug-toolbar` ... now I know that this is not equivalent to `pip install django-debug-toolbar==<LATEST>` :D
Anyway... 0 messages also with new version...

Answer (score 2):

This is [a reported bug](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/257) in [django-debug-toolbar on GitHub](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

A temporary workaround is mentioned in the issue thread.